# I picked them up and put them on the table. (about the second "them")

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, repetition

> There were some gloves on the floor, so I **picked them up and put them** on the table.

Could you explain why it's necessary to repeat "them" after "and"? Is it not clear the object after "and"? I think the sentence would be easier to read if we could write "... so I picked them up and put on the table."

I can't say like that, right? In my native language it's possible and often we don't repeat "them" after "and".

Comment: I think the simple answer is that *put* is a transitive verb here, so it needs an object.  If you leave out *them*, it's missing its object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinated verbs can share a single direct object in English, but the direct object must come *outside* of the coordinated phrase. For example:

> There were some gloves on the floor; I **saw and took** them.

However, that isn't possible with your sentence (because of "up" and "on the table"). Therefore, both direct objects must be written out, as in your original sentence.